# How to edit Default.Page.Template Content in DotNetNuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke

How to change home page content in DNN while creating a site itself.
I need to change different page. I created a new page and created Template. And I replaced inside Templates folder named (Default. page. template). But it is not working out. Provide me a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to create a site using the default template, edit that site to create your own site, and then save that as a site template (suitable named).  You can then use that site template to create sites with the page structure that you want.

The default page template (I believe) is used when you create new pages using the the Pages UI.  I don't believe that the default page template is used by the default site template.

If you have created a page and would like to apply a specific page template to the new page retroactively. To do this, go to the page that you want to change and append  ?ctl=ImportTab to the url.  That will bring up a dialog that allows you to change the emplate for a page with lots of options.  It

Comment: OK. But i tried to create a site template. That option is not available . It is showing only site view,settings,Import and Export icons. Is there any other option

Comment: Which DNN version?